# Rails retrieve a record if association record is not present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tables as follow. I want to retrieve a record on conditions of
1) if the association record is not present.
2) If an association record is present and status is active.

These are tables and its columns:

1) customers: email - string.
2) activities: type: 'gym'.
3) customer_activities(association table between above tables):
customer_id - integer .
activity_id - integer .
status - integer[enum with values: [:active, :dismiss, :complete]]

I am writing a query to retrieve `activities`:
when `customer_activities` record is not present OR
`customer_activities` is present and its status is: active.

**You have access to login customer with variable @customer**
The query I has written is:

```
Activity.joins(:customer_activities).
      where(type: ['gym']).
      where("(customer_activities.id IS NULL OR (customer_activities.status IN (?) AND customer_activities.customer_id = ?))", [1], @customer.id).
      references(:customer_activities).distinct
```

But it retrieves the activities when it's status association record status is active. But not when there are no `customer_activities`.

I know, I could do it in two queries.

```
activities = []
if @customer.activities.find_by(type: 'gym', status: 'active')
   activities.push(@customer.activities.find_by(type: 'gym', status: 'active'))
else
   activities.push(Activity.find_by(type: 'gym')
end
return activities
```

But I want to find it in a single query:

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity.where(id: @customer.joins(customer_activities: :activities).where(customer_activities: { status: 'active', activities: { type: 'gym' } }).ids).or(Activity.where(type: 'gym')).uniq
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time in helping. Here the status column is on `customer_activities` table not on `activities`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity.left_outer_joins(:customer_activities).
      where(type: ['gym']).
      where("(customer_activities.id IS NULL OR (customer_activities.status IN (?) AND customer_activities.customer_id = ?))", [1], [1], @customer.id).distinct
```